# Why printf("%.1f", 1) output 0.0

Tags: c, printf

I use the *codeblock*.

when the code is:

```
printf("%.1f", 1);
```

The program can run,and the output is `0.0`. I want to know why.
`

Comment: If you had typed `printf("%d", 1)`, `1` would be an `int`. If you type `printf("%f", 1)`, `1` is still an int. Get it? What you type in the string doesn't concern the compiler.

Comment: Assuming you are using GCC, add the `-Wformat` option to your compilation to get warning related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using wrong format specifier invokes *undefined behavior*. You may get either expected or unexpected result. Use `%d` instead as the argument passed to `printf` is `int` type or change `1` to `1.0` if you are using `%f`.

#### C11: 7.21.6 (p9):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: I would say "expect unexpected" in case of UB ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Change it to:

```
printf("%.1f", 1.0);
```

`f` conversion  specifier requires an argument of type `double` but you are passing an `int` value (`1` is of type `int`). Passing an argument of the wrong type to `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Swiss quality answer xD

Answer (score 0):

The format is incorrect , you should give a float or a double as the second argument to the printf function. The gcc compiler also gives a warning on such mistakes by programmers.

```
 printf("%.1f",1.23);
```

Output:

```
 1.2
```

Be carefull with these kind of mistakes. Good luck!